# fatal error: .h No such file or directory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

running on ubuntu 16.04 ros kinetic
on catkin_make i get this error.
there is a arm_interface.h file in omer/src/inclue/omer

```
 /home/armadillo2/catkin_ws/src/omer/src/arm_interface.cpp:2:50: fatal error: armadillo_hl_interface/arm_interface.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    /home/armadillo2/catkin_ws/src/omer/src/robot_test.cpp:5:50: fatal error: armadillo_hl_interface/arm_interface.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    omer/CMakeFiles/robot_testing.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'omer/CMakeFiles/robot_testing.dir/src/arm_interface.cpp.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [omer/CMakeFiles/robot_testing.dir/src/arm_interface.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    omer/CMakeFiles/robot_testing.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'omer/CMakeFiles/robot_testing.dir/src/robot_test.cpp.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [omer/CMakeFiles/robot_testing.dir/src/robot_test.cpp.o] Error 1
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:9581: recipe for target 'omer/CMakeFiles/robot_testing.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [omer/CMakeFiles/robot_testing.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(omer)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs

  moveit_core
  moveit_ros_planning
  moveit_ros_planning_interface

  actionlib_msgs
  actionlib

  tf
)
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES std_msgs geometry_msgs actionlib_msgs
)
```

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>omer</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The omer package</description>


  <maintainer email="armadillo2@todo.todo">armadillo2</maintainer>



  <license>TODO</license>



  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>actionlib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>actionlib_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>tf</build_depend>
  <build_depend>moveit_core</build_depend>
  <build_depend>moveit_ros_planning</build_depend>
  <build_depend>moveit_ros_planning_interface</build_depend>
  <build_depend>moveit_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>arm_interface</build_depend>

  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>

  <exec_depend>actionlib</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>actionlib_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>tf</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>moveit_core</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>moveit_ros_planning</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>moveit_ros_planning_interface</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>moveit_msgs</exec_depend>
 <exec_depend>arm_interface</exec_depend>


  <export>


  </export>
</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279114/fatal-error:-.h-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [omer91](https://answers.ros.org/users/33188/omer91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2018-01-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The #include statements in both **arm_interface.cpp** and **robot_test.cpp** seem to be looking for a header file called **arm_interface.h** which must be inside a directory called **armadillo_hl_interface**. Since this isn't the directory that contains that header file it's failing.

From your description the file is actually located in the **omer/src/include/omer** directory so try changing the #include in the two source files to:

```
#include "omer/arm_interface.h"
```

Hopefully then it will be able to find the header files correctly.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omer91](https://answers.ros.org/users/33188/omer91/) on 2018-01-08**:
thanks that solved it!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-08**:
If this solved your problem then please click the checkmark to mark the answer as correct.